# Is it possible to add new unique index to the existing database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have database table but without the index, and I want to add index `id` to that table, that will be uniqe for each row, how can I do this using mysql?

Comment: I take it you mean with JQuery or such like?

Comment: Could you clarify. You want to copy entries in an table over to another table that doesn't have those entries?

Comment: Was this question edited or something? I don't see an edit indication, and neither of those comments really make sense :/ He's just talking about adding a column to a MySql database table, not html Timbadu, and not copying one table to another Patrick ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a key on the table already you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE whatever ADD id Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

And remember you can add `FIRST` to the end of that line to make it the first column which would be a good idea for an id.

Comment: **PRIMARY KEY** in mysql might be better than **KEY**, but it depends I suppose :)

Comment: @WillBuck Fair enough, I just modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Wasn't a big deal darkajax, upvoted your answer because it was exactly what was asked for ;) Primary just adds a little more clarity!

Comment: Great, I didn't know auto_increment will do the job when using alter.